# How to keep <th> dynamic in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How do I loop though my Post keys to keep my table headers from being hard coded?  Right now my header row is just blank.

```
 $scope.posts.data = [
{
 "Post": {
   "id": "38",
   "title": "asdfasdf",
   "body": "asdfsadf",
   "created": "2014-08-01 17:37:27",
   "modified": "2014-08-01 17:37:27",
   "domain_id": "5286a27b-ebdd-491a-8e8d-46e64056922c"
 }
}]



<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in posts.data">{{key}}</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in posts.data">
            <td> {{key}} </td> <td> {{ value.Post.title}} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: First check your console for any errors... Try this http://plnkr.co/edit/fQCao6ZT73ma3LJ1zKE8?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working sample, hope it will help you

http://plnkr.co/edit/jBc3DJnzXNJUiVVwRAPw?p=preview

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in posts.data[0].Post">{{key}}</th>

    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="value in posts.data track by $index">
        <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in posts.data[$index].Post"> {{value}} </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

i had created a simple directive which just gives me a plain table with providing just the data

```
csapp.directive('csTable', function () {

    var templateFunction = function () {
        var html = '<table class="table table-bordered" data-ng-show="data.length > 0" style="overflow: auto; width: 100%">';
        html += '<thead>';
        html += '   <tr>';
        html += '       <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in data[0]">{{key}}</th>';
        html += '   </tr>';
        html += '</thead>';
        html += '<tbody>';
        html += '   <tr data-ng-repeat="row in data">';
        html += '       <td style="white-space: nowrap" data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in row">{{value}}</td>';
        html += '   </tr>';
        html += '</tbody>';
        html += '</table>';
        return html;
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: templateFunction,
        scope: { data: '=' }
    };
});
```

the problem you are mentioning is solved around here

```
      <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in data[0]">{{key}}</th>';
```

so it takes the first row from the data and does repeat on a single row.
that in your case would be something like

```
      <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in posts.data[0]">{{key}}</th>
```

hope this helps

Comment: I'm totally lost as to how to implement this.

Comment: doesnt this help you?? `<th ng-repeat="(key, value) in posts.data[0]">{{key}}</th>`

Comment: why are you loss? didnt answer help you. if not can you please setup a plunker. i will help you in getting that resolved